# Subjective General Knowledge

Tags: general-vs-specific

Is general knowledge only defined in relation to a specific group or in relation to the entire population?

I can think of two meanings.

1. General knowledge for a group of people is information you expect all people in that group to have been exposed to at some point in time (e.g. advanced calculus to math professors and history of curling to professional curlers).
2. General knowledge is information that you expect all people (regardless of cultural background etc.) to have been exposed to (e.g. who fought against whom in WWII, who founded Facebook).

I would tend to think of the first as "specific knowledge" and the second as "general knowledge". Is this a standard distinction or can all information be considered "general knowledge" to a specific population.

Comment: All communication happens in an intuitive context. Intuitively, we don't expect speakers of Polish to have an English vocabulary as part of their general knowledge. Intuitively, we do expect people who use this site to have a fundamental grasp of English vocabulary and syntax. We also expect them to gain access and and learn to use basic research tools as part of their [general knowledge](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). One person's *general knowledge* may be another person's *specific knowledge*.

Comment: I think if general knowledge is regardless of cultural background then there is very little it could cover: day and night, bodily functions and not much else. I expect there are still cultures that haven't heard of facebook or WWII.

Comment: I'm leaning toward your second meaning. I agree that the first meaning is specific to a population, and might not been know by all of that group. Some aspects of advanced calculus (e.g., tensors) would not be known to all math professors. This is quite specific knowledge that, say, a math professor of linear algebra would have been exposed to but would not necessarily be conversant.

Comment: Haven't heard of Facebook?! Surely you can't be serious :)

Comment: Tribes in the Amazon for example. I wouldn't bet they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think neither.

General knowledge is usually defined in relation to an *individual.*

Example: *John is highly qualified in Physics but he also has extensive general knowledge.*

This means that John knows about many different subjects. He probably reads widely in many different fields, current affairs, history, politics, literature theatre, the arts and so on.
As well as being a specialist (in Physics), he is also a generalist. 
A person who has a great deal of general knowledge would do well on a quiz show.

Comment: So you are saying that a specific piece of information is neither general knowledge nor specific but rather a person has general knowledge if they know many pieces of information in many different fields. So the sentence "how do you not know that?! It is general knowledge!" is improper usage?

Comment: "how do you not know that?! It is general knowledge!" would be a peculiar answer. "it is common knowledge" is the usual phrasing.

Comment: I think, at least as far as my question is concerned common knowledge and general knowledge are synonymous.

Comment: The correct phrase is "How do you not know that? It is **common** knowledge!"  -  I see that Avon beat me to it!

Comment: @Benjy Kessler - No, they are definitely not synonyms.

Comment: I agree with chasly. General knowledge as an answer to that question would mean "it is knowledge I have gathered outside of my profession/specialist training". Common knowledge means it is commonly (widely) known.

Comment: @Avon: I parse ***common** knowledge* as "knowledge which is *held in common* by [almost] everyone". In contrast to ***general** knowledge*, which is knowledge not specific to some particular domain (so anyone *might* know it even if they're not a specialist in the relevant domain).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Benjy Kessler indeed meant "common knowledge" and not "general knowledge" (or alternatively, not getting into the semantics, but rather the more general meaning of the question), I think that one always needs to specify what culture and what society is being considered, when asking whether something is specific or common knowledge.

My gut says that there is such a thing as being too specific -- to say that the history of curling is common knowledge among curling fans may be considering too small a group. On the other hand, to say that the Jewish holidays are common knowledge among Jews (not even practicing Jews, at that) is a little more easily said. There are things I wouldn't expect a Christian to know about Islam, but I would expect any Muslim to know, regardless of their level of observance. There are things I wouldn't expect a Finn to know about Canadian history, but I would expect a Canadian to know, etc.

Either way, "regardless of cultural background" is never something you can say. Maybe Western culture is all there is in your eyes, but obviously that's also specifying a certain cultural background - albeit a pretty common one.

Answer (score 0):

General knowledge is clearly defined in your meaning #1. As for meaning #2, the definition there speaks of common knowledge which is information known throughout a community( population ).

It's common knowledge to know where the local Burger King or Walgreens is located in your city or town. It's general knowledge to know that Burger King has Whoppers and not Big Macs and that Walgreens has bandaids, headache pills, and shaving cream etc.

An outlander can visit a relative for the first time and know that there are local places to get something to eat ( common knowledge ), but doesn't know which place has what to eat on their menus ( General knowledge ).