# Not a malapropism but a ... what?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say someone rebukes me for being ignorant of a well-known fact. They say:

"Everyone knows that; it's *general* knowledge"

when I know that in that context, the normal usage is:

"Everyone knows that; it's *common* knowledge"

Incorrectly using '*general*' when you mean '*common*' isn't a malapropism because the words don't sound similar. I'm sure there is a term for this (other than 'error' or 'mistake') but what is it?

Comment: Isn't "general knowledge" an idiom, along with "common knowledge"? Why is it wrong?

Comment: @Andrew Leach - Fair enough. I've edited my question.

Comment: Same applies: "General knowledge" could easily be used in those circumstances, just as "common knowledge" could be (that is, the fact could be the answer to a General Knowledge quiz question).

Comment: Okay - it's clear I haven't phrased the question correctly. I'll see if I can come up with a better example.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I thought [this comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260132/subjective-general-knowledge#comment570669_260136) clarified your question: *"General knowledge as an answer to that question would mean "it is knowledge I have gathered outside of my profession/specialist training". Common knowledge means it is commonly (widely) known."*

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what precisely it is you're asking. Are you referring to phrases that basically _mean_ the same thing as a fixed expression, but which uses different words than the standard expression? For example, if someone says, “We’re going to have a picnic tomorrow, weather allowing”, the last bit is easily understandable and means precisely the same thing as the established, fixed expression _weather permitting_; but it is still perceived as ‘off’ precisely because there **is** a fixed expression, and _weather allowing_ is not it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested, **solecism** may be an apt term, but **barbarism** could be even closer, seeing that the example given in the question shows a fault involving a single word. This summary of a section from the Roman grammarian Donatus's *Ars Grammatica* neatly distinguishes the two:

> A *barbarism* is defined as a fault of a single part of speech, generally a word form...while a *solecism* is a fault of a part of speech used in connection with other linguistic units.

from [*Ars Poetriae: Rhetorical and Grammatical Invention at the Margin of Literacy* By William Michael Purcell](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mw0ygQ2oky0C&pg=PA25&dq=%22solecism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBmoVChMIiO6-94vhxgIVyCuICh2mBg4U#v=onepage&q=%22solecism%22&f=false)

The patronizing, puritanical air of *barbarism* is admittedly a long way from the comical nature of *malapropism*, and Ngram Views shows its (as well as *solecism*'s) use steadily declining to almost nil today. Yet modern dictionaries still maintain its meaning (though always secondary to the sense of "barbaric act") much the way it was described in the 4th C.E. century by Donatus:

**barbarism**

> **3.**  An error in language use within a single word, such as a mispronunciation.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barbarism)

> **2a.** The use of words, forms, or expressions considered incorrect or
>   unacceptable. **b.** A specific word, form, or expression so used.

(AHCD, 4th Edition)

Answer (score 4):

You might be searching for *catachresis,* which is defined by google as "the use of a word in a way that is not correct, for example, the use of *mitigate* for *militate*." While *mitigate* and *militate* sound similar, this is not characteristic of catachresis. Catachresis is more general, I believe, and applies to confusions of semantically similar words. Such an error could be called a *catachresism*.

Comment: That sounds close. What I want is a word that means *unintentional* catachresis.  Maybe ***solecism*** is even nearer.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that the expressions have unique set phrase definitions, so each would be **preferable** for its specific use:

- *[Common knowledge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/common-knowledge?q=common%20knowledge)*

> Something known by most people:
>   *it’s common knowledge that no one has yet found a cure for cancer*
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

- *[General knowledge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/general-knowledge?q=general%20knowledge)*

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN] Knowledge of a broad range of facts about various
>   subjects:
>   *this quiz tests your general knowledge*
>
> [AS MODIFIER]:
>   *a round of general knowledge questions*
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

But it would be quite parochial to **impose** the set phrase interpretation. The adjectival elements of each expression are similar in their meaning and both can be combined with the noun *knowledge* with insignificant shift in meaning:

*[Common](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/common)*

> adjective (commoner, commonest)
>
> 1.0 Occurring, found, or done often; prevalent:
>   *salt and pepper are the two most common seasonings
>
>   common misspellings
>
>   it’s common for a woman to be depressed after giving birth*
>
> 1.3 ***Ordinary***; of ordinary qualities; without special rank or position:
>   *the dwellings of common people
>
>   a common soldier*
>
> 1.4 (Of a quality) of a sort or level to be generally expected:
>   *common decency*
>
> 1.5 Of the most familiar type:
>   *the common or vernacular name*
>
> 2.0 Shared by, coming from, or done by two or more
>   people, groups, or things:
>   *the two republics' common border problems
>
>   common to both communities*
>
> 2.1 ***Belonging to or involving the whole of a community*** or the public at large:
>   common land
>   <sub>*ODO **Emphasis** added*</sub>

*Common knowledge* yields the reasonable meaning:
***Ordinary knowledge belonging to the whole community***

vs.

*General knowledge* yields the reasonable meaning:
***Normal knowledge affecting all people***

> *[General](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/general)*
>
> adjective
>
> 1.0 ***Affecting or concerning all or most people*** or things; widespread:
>   *books of general interest
>
>   the general opinion was that prices would fall*
>
> 1.1 Not specialized or limited in range of subject, application, activity, etc.
>   *brush up on your general knowledge*
>
> 1.2 (Of a rule, principle, etc.) true for all or most cases.
>
> 1.3 ***Normal*** or usual:
>   *it is not general practice to confirm or deny such reports*
>   <sub>*ODO **Emphasis** added*</sub>

---

*[Alternative](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alternative)*:

> adjective
>
> 1 [ATTRIBUTIVE] (Of one or more things) available as another
>   possibility or choice:
>   *the various alternative methods for resolving
>   disputes*
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

*Common knowledge* is about half again more common than *general knowledge* in the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=common%20knowledge%2Cgeneral%20knowledge&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccommon%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgeneral%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0), but they have been roughly tracking together for about 75 years:

[image]

**Conclusion**

It is certainly appropriate to interpret *common knowledge* and *general knowledge* as set phrases, but neither phrase is dominant enough to exclude the simple combination of the words. Therefor, in appropriate contexts *general knowledge* remains an acceptable **alternative** for *common knowledge*.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say that phrase is *nonidiomatic* -- not an idiom. We had a discussion here once about the difference between the idiomatic "back and forth" and the equally valid but nonidiomatic "forth and back."

Answer (score 0):

**[Freudian slip:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/freudian%20slip?s=t)** an inadvertent mistake in speech or writing that reveals unconscious intentions.
**[slip of the tongue:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slip+of+the+tongue)** an unintentional error in speaking
**[misstatement:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misstatement)** a statement that contains a mistake